# Forward all network packets from server A to server B (WAN) Ubuntu

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, ubuntu-12.04, forwarding

I currently run a game server on a VPS and will shortly be moving VPS provider. To make the migration easier on the players I would like players to be able to use the original IP for a short while by forwarding all packets from the old server to the new one.

I know this will add additional latency, but I will be displaying a message showing the new IP and will be warning them about the added latency if they use the original IP.

The two servers are **not** on the same internal network.

I'd like all of these to be valid;

```
Client --> Server A --> Server B
Server B --> Client
Client --> Server B
```

Eg, the client can connect directly to B, but if they connect to A it will redirect to B. Server B sends its data directly to the client in all cases.

Server A will do nothing apart from forward packets (e.g. the game server is *not* running there)

I know this might not be possible, but it'd be great if someone could help me out with this.

Oh, as it's a game server most traffic is UDP and both servers run Ubuntu 12.0.4

Thanks

Comment: I know it's _common_ to use raw IP addresses for gameservers, but you really should use hostnames in the DNS, to avoid this problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

> Client --> Server A --> Server B

You will have to use dual NAT for this, on `Server A` :

1. `DNAT` incoming packets to `Server A` to `Server B`
2. Also do `SNAT` so that return traffic will be send back through `Server A`

Something like this :

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d $Server_A_ip_address -j DNAT --to-destination $Server_B_ip_address
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d $Server_B_ip_address -j SNAT --to-source $Server_A_ip_address
```

---

Others case are more easy to handle :

> Server B --> Client

On `Server B` : `iptables -A OUTPUT -s $Server_B_ip_address -j ACCEPT`

> Client --> Server B

On `Server B` : `iptables -A INPUT -d $Server_B_ip_address -j ACCEPT`

---

Of course, for all these, it is recommanded to specify protocols and ports. My samples are too much permissive because i don't know your ports/protocols.